# Mocha & Chai Async testing in the browser

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, mocha.js, chai

I am not being able to run async tests with mocha.

Here is my code

```
describe('Brightcove Wrapper',function(){
    describe("#init()", function() {
        it("Should inject the brightcove javascript", function(done){
            BCL.init(function(){
                //expect(window).to.have.property('brightcove');
                console.log(this) //window object
                done();
                console.log('this shows in the log too')
            });
        });
    });
})
```

both logs show, but done() is never called.

Answer (score -1):

In my function, I was adding a string to the document's body, which apparently upsets mocha. I changed the code to append my string to a div with an ID, and the tests passed.